# Determine the minimum register size

Tags: embedded, bit, cpu-registers, signed

I am actually new to embedded systems. I have a question on determining the minimum register size to store a particular value. Here is the question:

1. Why do it need a minimum of 8 bits register size to store 0xFFFFFFF1 (signed numbers)
2. Why do it need a minimum of 16 bits register size to store 0b010010110111 (signed numbers)

Comment: I think more information is needed. Why do you believe those are the minimum register sizes required?

Comment: Your first example is a bit wrong as you've shown a 32-bit representation, unless you are trying to store the value of "-15" in which case you can do so in a similar 2's complement manner in a 5-bit register (which, while uncommon for general purpose registers, do exist in special purpose functional blocks).  To really answer your question though, you have to consider what *other* values are allowed - for the given values it could be possible to ignore constant leading bits, or for those values *alone* omit the "register" altogether and just provide the value with fixed wires.

Comment: Just guessing, but I don't think you're getting the difference between a bit and a byte. A byte has 8 bits and bits are single values 0 or 1. When specifying numbers in hex (e.g a prefix or 0x), each character is 4 bits or a nibble and there two nibbles in a byte.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this exercise is to get you to understand where the sign bit is in a signed number or where the sign bits are since they sign extend forever.  A positive number will have an infinite number of 0s and a negative an infinite number of 1s.  so long as you have at least one you can represent that number so your first one is 1111....1110001  the sign bit starts on bit 4 so it only takes a 5 bit register minimum to hold that number.   Your second example 0b010010110111  we have to assume the msbit there sign extends and in that case bit 11 indicates sign so you at minimum need a 12 bit register.  Now if your processor does not have a 5 bit then whatever the next size up is the minimum (8?).  And if your processor does not have a 12 bit register then the next size up is 16.